# Buscar por un campo de la base de datos realm

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

Alguien sabe como se realizaría una consulta en Realm donde se recorriera toda la tabla y se fueran cogiendo las tuplas donde el nombre de un campo se correspondiera con el que yo tengo.

Es decir, si tuvieramos una base de datos de una biblioteca, y queremos coger los usuarios con un determinado apellido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola amigo es fácil solo debes hacer algo como esto

```
RealmResults<Usuario> Usuarios
Usuarios = realm.where("Tu modelo").equalTo("Nombre de tu columna ", "Valor a buscar").findAll();
```

y de esta manera te saldrán los resultados acorde a tu filtro.
Espero te sirva amigo.